# Wake up ESP8266 with multiple GPIOs

Tags: esp8266

I am building a ESP-07 based IOT device, that detects the status of 4 doors. The device must connect to WiFi and send an http request, when 1 of 4 doors is opened. I want to place a reed switch, for example on each door. The battery consumption should be minimal, so I thought of using deepsleep () or something similar to keep the device asleep most of the time, or keep it completely off (like most Dash buttons does).

I have studied several options, but almost all use a single GPIO to wake up the device. For example, this option wakes the device up if D3 goes high, and sleep if D3 is low.

    #include 
    #include 
    #define WAKE_PIN D3

```cpp
const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* pass = "PASSWORD";

extern "C" {
    #include "gpio.h"
}

extern "C" {
    #include "user_interface.h"
}

void setup(){
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    uint8_t i = 0;
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && i++ < 10) delay(250);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Setup");
    pinMode(WAKE_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    gpio_init(); // Initilise GPIO pins
}

void loop(){
    Serial.println("Do something...");
    if(!digitalRead(WAKE_PIN)){
        sleep();
    }
    delay(1000);
}

void sleep(){
    Serial.println("Going to sleep...");
    delay(10);
    wifi_fpm_set_sleep_type(LIGHT_SLEEP_T); // set sleep type
    gpio_pin_wakeup_enable(GPIO_ID_PIN(WAKE_PIN), GPIO_PIN_INTR_HILEVEL); 
    wifi_fpm_open(); // Enables force sleep
    wifi_fpm_do_sleep(0xFFFFFFF); // Sleep for longest possible time
    delay(100);
    Serial.println("Woke up!");
}
```

Here, GPIO_ID_PIN(2) corresponds to GPIO2 on ESP8266-01 , GPIO_PIN_INTR_LOLEVEL for a logic low, can also do other interrupts.

My question is:

Can I use more than one GPIO, that is, one of 4 GPIOs to wake up the device?

I have the problem of knowing which of the four doors has been opened!

The other option I have thought is to use a latch circuit that turns on the (previously turned off) device using a single GPIO. Something like this:

[image: Latch circuit]

What I meant is that ESP-07 can latch its own power on (and off) using an MOSFET pair connected in parallel with the physical (momentary contact) power switch. When the power switch is pressed (or a door is opened), one of the  first things the ESP8266 needs to do is latch the power on. When the current iteration of this programm is done, it simply turns it's own power off again.

```cpp
#define POWER_SW   2   // GPIO connected to POWER_LATCH

void LatchOn() {
    pinMode(POWER_SW, OUTPUT); 
    digitalWrite(POWER_SW, HIGH);
}


void LatchOff() {
    digitalWrite(POWER_SW, LOW);
}
```

What I want to know is how I can use more than one signal from each of the 4 doors, or, use 4 GPIOs to activate the latch circuit. I tried with one single door connected to the GPIO that wakes the chip up. I want to extend the functionality of my program so that any of the 4 doors turns the chip on.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.
I have opened a thread about this topic in [Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=523073) as well.

Comment: do you have the option of using a logic IC?

Comment: Sounds good! Any ideas?

Comment: Idea: Wire the  four door-GPIOs together with an OR gate, connect that to your wakeup pin, but still connect all door-GPIOs to 4 different GPIO pins on your ESP8266. When a wakeup is triggered (because ANY of the door GPIOs were triggered), read the state of the 4 door-GPIOs, act on it, then go back to sleep. You can use simple diode-ORs or CMOS (N)OR logic gates for this.

Comment: Also asked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/48279829

Comment: A friend from Arduino Forum told me that I can use a bunch of diodes to have all door switches trigger two pins: the shared wake-up pin, and a unique one for each switch. I have no idea how I could do that. 

Any idea of what a circuit with these characteristics would look like? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if an TTL-CMOS OR gate like CD4072 works with 3V3 logic. A simple circuit with diodes or resistor looks better. Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/product/cd74ac32 . PDIP package, four 2-input OR gates, voltage working for 3.3V and 5V as well.

Comment: I think Diodes would use less power that an IC, but...

Comment: Great! I will try with CD74AC32 as well. Thanks!

Comment: How to make a circuit like that with diodes? It seems better to me, but I have no idea

Comment: And what if I use the ADC or analog input of the ESP-07? I think that with an array of resistors I can determine which of the 4 doors has been opened. Something like that --> [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-access-5-buttons-through-1-Arduino-input/)

Comment: Hello! 

I have an idea. What if I connect each door using a DPST (double pole single throw) switch? 

This would be the scheme using two single switches.

[link](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/attachments/doors-png.144079/)

My idea is to use the same switch to connect at the same time the RESET PIN and the corresponding pin to each door (for example, GPIO12).

Would there be problems if two doors open at the same time? Would not the RESET pin be overloaded when two switches are connected to VCC?

Comment: Hi!

I have made a small card to connect my ESP8266. It is supposed to connect the GPIOs corresponding to the 4 doors I mentioned. My idea is to use, as I said before, a simple switch on each door, to connect each one to GND and the corresponding pin. I have connected each pin (GPIO12, ..., GPIO15) to the inputs of the 74HC32 and the output to the RESET (so that any of the doors can wake up to the ESP8266 of deep sleep.) 

74HC32 is already connected to GND and VCC.

 Click to see the schematics  --> [link](https://goo.gl/6Dv9zM)  My question is: Ok what I have done?

Comment: @JoseAlfredoSanchezDiaz - any chance you can draw a schematic for wiring of your example above - the code was really helpful to me in trying to set up sleep mode in my own project, but I can only make the esp go to sleep with a button, not wake up.